# Optional parameter needed

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net

I have a legacy application, which contains a database helper class.  The client calls the following function:

```
 Public Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal connection As DbConnection, _
                                                           ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                                           ByVal commandText As String, _
                                                           ByVal ParamArray commandParameters() As DbParameter) As DbDataReader
                ' Pass through the call to private overload using a null transaction value
                Return ExecuteReader(connection, CType(Nothing, DbTransaction), commandType, commandText, commandParameters, dbConnectionOwnership.External)

End Function
```

As you can see the function above calls an overloaded ExecuteReader, which is detailled below:

```
Private Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal connection As DbConnection, _
                                                            ByVal transaction As DbTransaction, _
                                                            ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                                            ByVal commandText As String, _
                                                            ByVal commandParameters() As DbParameter, _
                                                            ByVal connectionOwnership As dbConnectionOwnership) As DbDataReader

            If (connection Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("connection")

            Dim mustCloseConnection As Boolean = False
            Dim cmd As DbCommand
            ' Create a command and prepare it for execution
            If TypeOf (connection) Is SqlConnection Then
                cmd = New SqlCommand
            ElseIf TypeOf (connection) Is OracleConnection Then
                cmd = New OracleCommand
            End If
            Try
                ' Create a reader
                Dim dataReader As DbDataReader

                PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, mustCloseConnection)
                ' Call ExecuteReader with the appropriate CommandBehavior
                If connectionOwnership = dbConnectionOwnership.External Then
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Else
                    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                End If

                ' Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
                Dim canClear As Boolean = True
                Dim commandParameter As DbParameter
                For Each commandParameter In cmd.Parameters
                    If commandParameter.Direction <> ParameterDirection.Input Then
                        canClear = False
                    End If
                Next

                If (canClear) Then cmd.Parameters.Clear()

                Return dataReader
            Catch
                If (mustCloseConnection) Then connection.Close()
                Throw
            End Try
        End Function
```

I cannot see a way of setting the CommandTimeout property without refactoring the code significantly.  This function is called lots of times from the client - there is only one case where the commandtimeout needs to be changed.  Some quick ideas I had were:

> 1) Set the commandtimeout as an instance variable (it is not a static
>   class).  This does not seem correct though.
>   2) Use an Optional
>   parameter with a default value of: 30.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

I realise I probably should be using an ORM but this is a legacy application.

Comment: What is the problem with using an optional parameter?

Comment: @Matt Wilko, you can't use a param array and an optional parameter in the same function signature I believe.

Comment: Maybe you can create a 2nd function with the same name but with an added parameter for the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with optional parameter, but instead of using hard-coded default value of `30` seconds I would use default value of `-1` and add extra `if` statement to check if specific value is provided and if the default timeout should be overridden.

In this way you would still be able to set default timeout in connection string and use specific timeout where needed.